# Windows 10 USB 3.0 thumb drive format popup

Tags: windows-7, usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

I have a PNY 32GB usb 3.0 thumb drive.  When I plug it in, i continually get an error saying drive i: is not formatted, and an option to format.  This popup continues about 1/s.  I disabled Auto-Play to prevent this from happening, and when I plug in the drive, my taskbar continues to 'flicker'.

Does anyone know how I can fix the drive?  I've tried diskpart with no success.

**list drive**

```
Disk 1  Online   335GB  1024KB
...
Disk 7  No Media  0B     0B  <--- This is the USB Drive
```

**select disk 7**

```
Disk 7 is now the selected disk.
```

**create partition primary**

```
No usable free extent count be found. it may be that there is insufficient free space to create a partition at the specified size and offset. speci....
```

**list partition**

```
There are no partition on this disk to show
```

**clean**

```
Virtual Disk Service error:
There is no media in the device
```

Comment: What makes you think it has a file system?

Comment: If you don't have any data on this that you need, then when the option pops up to format it, then format it if you want to be able to use it when you plug it into the Windows 7 PC USB ports. Again, this is assuming you DO NOT have any data on this USB thumb drive you CURRENTLY need to worry about. If the thing is not formatted or in unusable Windows format, then I assume once you connect it to a Windows USB port, Windows will say, **"hey, you plugged in this USB drive I cannot read, should I format it so you can use it in Windows"**. Based on your description, it seems as simple as that!!

Comment: @Ramhound There is no filesystem on it.  That is the reason I tried to create a partition, so that I could then format it.  Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish I have no data on the drive.  I tried to format the drive when the prompt came up with no luck.  I also tried using diskpart and again no luck.